# How to reset a numerical sequence after a new suffix in a R vector

Tags: r, dataframe, prefix, seq

I have created a dataframe with a group column and an individual identifier which incorporates the group name and a number formatted to a standardised three digit code:

```
library(stringr)
group = rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each = 3)
df <- data.frame(group, indiv = paste(group, str_pad(1:9, pad = 0, width = 3 , "left"), sep = ""))
```

All well and good, but how would I go about resetting the individual identifier each time there is a new prefix, for this ideal result:

```
df2 <- data.frame(group, indiv = c("A001", "A002", "A003", 
                                   "B001", "B002", "B003", 
                                   "C001", "C002", "C003"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may group by 'group', use `substr` to extract the first character from 'indiv' and use `sprintf` to format the sequence (`row_number()`)

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  mutate(indiv = sprintf('%s%03d', substr(indiv, 1, 1), row_number())) %>%
  ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 9 × 2
  group indiv
  <chr> <chr>
1 A     A001 
2 A     A002 
3 A     A003 
4 B     B001 
5 B     B002 
6 B     B003 
7 C     C001 
8 C     C002 
9 C     C003
```

---

Or compactly with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, indiv := sprintf('%s%03d', group, rowid(group))]
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
df$indiv <-  with(df, sprintf('%s%03d', group, 
       ave(seq_along(group), group, FUN = seq_along)))
```

Comment: This worked an absolute treat :)

Answer (score 1):

Another base R solution:

```
df <- data.frame(group, 
            indiv = paste(group, str_pad(rep(1:3, 3), 
                    pad = 0, width = 3 , "left"), sep = ""))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative approach using akrun's `sprintf`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  mutate(indiv = paste0(group, sprintf("%03d", row_number())))
```

output:

```
  group indiv
  <chr> <chr>
1 A     A001 
2 A     A002 
3 A     A003 
4 B     B001 
5 B     B002 
6 B     B003 
7 C     C001 
8 C     C002 
9 C     C003
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sprintf()` alone inside `mutate`:

```
library(dplyr)

df |> 
  group_by(group) |> 
  mutate(indiv = sprintf("%s%03d", group, 1:n()))
```

`%s`: character strings, in this case `group`.

`%03d`: Add 3 leading zeroes to an integer (`%d`), in this case the row number in the grouping.